# Parsing Html content using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

This is my HTML source

```
             <li>
                 <a href="/info/some1>Item 1<br>
                    <span class="deets">111</span>
                 </a>
             </li>

             <li>
                 <a href="/info/some2>Item 2<br>
                    <span class="deets">222</span>
                 </a>
             </li>

             <li>
                 <a href="/info/some3>Item 3<br>
                    <span class="deets">333</span>
                 </a>
             </li>
```

This is my Java program to get the content & it filters the HTML tags

```
    try {   
        myurl = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com");  
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();

        InputStream result = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;)
            //append all content & separate using line separator
        sb.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        String final_result = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");    

        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        tv.setText(final_result);


    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv.setText("not working");
    }
```

1. Is there an easier way using Jsoup to parse the HTML content using Java instead of Regex
2. Is there a way to get only the required contents. So here I just want the contents "Item 2 - 222"

   ```
            <li>
                <a href="/info/some2>Item 2<br>
                   <span class="deets">222</span>
                </a>
            </li>
   ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336845/how-to-parse-ul-li-tags-using-jsoup-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for easy parsing using jsoup:

```
// To parse the html page
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.website.com").get();
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse("<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>" + "<body> <p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>");

String content = doc.body().text();

// To get specific elements such as links
Element links = doc.select("a[href]");
for(Element e: links){
    System.out.println("link: " + e.attr("abs:href"));
}
```

To learn more, visit [Jsoup Docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am able to implement the same logic in an easier way using Jsoup but I wanted to get content output like this "Item2 222" from the whole HTML source. How do I reference the "Item 2" and "222" in between other values.

Comment: Could you explain the desired results in a bit more detail and specifically?

Comment: Thank you again. The output i wanted was "Item 2  222" from the HTML source in the question. I got it working anyways. I used Elements href  = doc.select("div.featured-resource > div.module > ul > li > a[href=/info/some2]" ); System.out.println(href.text());

Comment: you can use doc.getElementById("Item2") and then respective function to get the desired results

Comment: Ok so here is my html source again http://pastebin.com/8bMHbWCh         All i want is "BBC Channel 555" as the output for java from the HTML. There is no ID for each element. Can i still extract that info using Jsoup or regex anyhow.

Comment: You can do it by using both Jsoup and Regex. For Jsoup, try putting the lists in a class and then retrieve the text using doc.getElementsbyClass("className").text(); and compare the results in a for each loop till you find BBC Channel 555

Comment: I do not have access to modify the HTML code to add class names. It is on a website and I can only pull info from it. Is there any other possible way to extract in this Case.

Comment: Not sure. I usually use regex for these purposes. In Jsoup, You can retrieve all the lists and check if BBC Channel there in the list. This way is not very efficient for large source codes but can be useful for small ones